# Go returning http status codes when using rs.cors

Tags: http, go, cors, gorilla

When using rs.cors to enable Cors on a go web service, returning http status codes other than 200 (for instance, returning http.StatusTooManyRequests) results in a CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localsrv:3021/test?status=toomany' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Using rs.cors is not a requirement, but I was unable to successfully get CORS working in some cases without it.

Here is some sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func main() {

    rtr := mux.NewRouter()
    rtr.HandleFunc("/test", test).Methods("GET")
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(rtr)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3021",
        (limitMiddleware(handler))); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to start server: %s", err.Error())
    }

}

func limitMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        params := r.URL.Query()
        if params["status"][0] == "toomany" {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusTooManyRequests), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("test()")
}
```

JavaScript request that should generate a StatusTooManyRequests ends up with a CORS error instead of the HTTP 429.

```
axios.get("http://okami:3021/test?status=toomany")
  .then(res => {
    console.log("stuff http://okami:3021/test result",  res);
}); //axios
```

Is there a way to use rs.cors so that CORS kicks in when there is a CORS issue, and http error codes can return when there is not a CORS issue?
Basically, unless the system returns HTTP 200, CORS kicks in.

This should be simple, but I'm scratching my head on this one.

Let me know if it would be better to abandon rs.cors and work on manually enabling cors instead and I can start another question for that!

Answer (score 0):

The function returned by limitMiddleware executes *before* the cors middleware (the next argument). Reorder your handlers:

```
rtr := mux.NewRouter()
rtr.HandleFunc("/test", test).Methods("GET")
handler := cors.Default().Handler(limitMiddleware(rtr))
http.ListenAndServe(":3021", handler)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify Cors, Please try this code inside your main(){ ... }

```
    port := ":9000"
    headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
    methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"})
    origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})

    err = http.ListenAndServe(port, handlers.CORS(headers, methods, origins))
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("Error starting server: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to use rs.cors so that CORS kicks in when there is a CORS issue, and http error codes can return when there is not a CORS issue?

Unless you handle cors, you will get that as error, so the fix of this issue is to fix cors.

> Using rs.cors is not a requirement, but I was unable to successfully get CORS working in some cases without it.

you can handle cors by setting `http.ResponseWriter` Header value. you can do it so

```
 func getGoogle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
}
```

or replace "*" with your front end url.